# Complex array initialization in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

There is a problem when I want to define a complex array:

```
#include<complex.h>

int main(){

int matrix=1000;
std::complex<double> y[matrix];

}
```

The error is "Variable length array  of non-POD element type 'std::complex'
Is there something wrong with the definition of array here?

Comment: You probably want `<complex>`, not `<complex.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of array only works with a length that is a constant expression, i.e. the length must be known at compile time.

To get a array of variable length, use an `std::vector<std::complex<double>> y (matrix);`

You should use `std::vector` (or `std::array` in some cases) over C-style arrays anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can't statically allocate a C++ array with size being a regular variable, since the value of `matrix` is not known until the program is executed. Try dynamically allocating your array:

`std::complex<double> y = new std::complex<double>[matrix]`

When you are doing using it, call:

`delete[] y`

Comment: Why would he need to call `delete[]`? I only see reference types?

Answer (score 1):

The size of arrays must be know at compile time. It must be a constant expression. The value of matrix is only known at runtime. You must make matrix a constant to work.

```
const int matrix=1000;
```

The other way around is to use a vector whose size is variable and is initialized at runtime.

```
int matrix=1000;
std::vector<std::complex<double>> y(matrix);
```

Comment: But I also have a line of code as
double yf[matrix];
and compiler is not giving any errors for that. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't allow `variable length arrays`, either do it dynamically or use a `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler thinks that you are declaring a variable-length array, since `matrix` is non-`const`. Just make it constant and things should work:

```
const int matrix = 1000;
std::complex<double> y[matrix];
```

The error stems from the fact that variable-length arrays are only allowed for "dumb" data types, e.g. int/char/void* and structs, but not classes like `std::complex`.

Comment: The question is tagged C++. VLAs are not allowed for any type.

Comment: I wasn't aware that VLAs aren't supported in MS VC++. They work in g++, so if that's all you need to target, they will do the job. Whether the convenience outweighs the portability concerns is another issue.

Comment: I don't know about MSVC. The point is that they aren't allowed in the C++ language. They may be present on some compilers as an extension (which can be usually be switched off by asking for a particular standard.)

Comment: I get your point. I feel that sometimes compiler extensions can be awfully nice, and depending on the circumstances, that may be more important than standards purity. It's the [pragmatist/realist split](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/03/17.html) at work :-)